# Difference between DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail and DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want to send an email after a registration process in a DNN module. When i searched i found that there is an in-built mail class in dnn. But it contains two methods - **SendEmail** and **SendMail**. What is the difference between these two?And which one i have to opt in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SendEmail` was introduced in DNN 5.3, and greatly simplifies the API.  If you're able to use the `SendEmail` method, I would recommend it, it's much simpler than `SendMail` (which always requires SMTP information, even though it's almost always pulled from settings).

If you're looking for

- from
- to
- subject
- body

with optional

- sender
- attachments

then `SendEmail` is what you want.

Comment: so in SendEmail, will they take the SMTP settings automatically?

Comment: Yes, the SMTP settings are pulled from the SMTP section in Host Settings (what would happen if you passed `null` for those arguments in `SendMail`)

Comment: In SendEmail where's the optional reply-to, I'm getting attachment when putting in an extra comma but no reply-to is coming up?

Comment: that should actually say (and now does say) sender, rather than reply-to.  It's the second parameter.  If you want reply-to instead of sender, you'll have to stick with `SendMail`.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on bdukes answer...

**SendEmail() is great for sending basic emails.**

**SendMail() is great for sending emails where you need to access additional options.**  Things like **CC addresses, BCC addresses, and Body Style** can be set using this function.  The function call looks a lot more complicated, but other than a few additional parameters, there is nothing difficult about using SendMail(), so don't be discouraged if it takes an extra minute to set up the function call.

**When using SendMail() if blank strings are used for the SMTP parameters, the function will use the DNN SMTP settings.**

Here is a short article by Chris Hammond that shows how simple using SendMail() is, http://weblogs.asp.net/christoc/archive/2006/06/23/DotNetNuke-Daily-Tip-6_2D00_23_2D00_06.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think the SendMail internally refers the SendEmail option to send mail.Check their parameters for more details and use the one that is appropriate for your situation.

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail(String fromAddress, String senderAddress, String toAddress, String subject, String body)
DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail(UserInfo user, MessageType msgType, PortalSettings settings)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, there isn't any delegation between `SendMail` and `SendEmail`. In fact, only one of the `SendEmail` implementations delegates; there are three separate methods which fully implement the email sending logic.