# Getting reply-to working when sending email from DNN

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

SendEmail and I currently want to add in a reply-to address.

Currently I've got

```
DNN.SendEmail(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body)
```

and I noticed in the answer to this question (link below) there is an optional reply-to, but it does't appear to be coming up for me.

[Difference between DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail and DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752548/difference-between-dotnetnuke-services-mail-mail-sendemail-and-dotnetnuke-servic)

Any ideas on how to get the reply-to?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The method is as follows:

```
Mail.SendEmail("replyto@email.com", "from@email.com", "to@email.com", "Subject", "BODY");
```

For some reason they call it "from Address" and "sender address"